# Ajax is only being called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a follow and unfollow button. Of course, when you click the follow button, the unfollow button should appear. When you click the follow button, the unfollow button should appear.

As of right now, when you click "follow", the database gets updated, the "follow" button disappears  and the "unfollow" button appears. The problem is that if I click the "unfollow" button again, nothing happens. Even if I put a console.log('test'); in top of the scripts, nothing works. Here is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('test');

    $('.follow').click(function(){
        console.log('yes');
            var userid = $(this).attr("id");
            var dataString = 'id='+ userid ;
            var self = this;                
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax/follow",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(result) {
                        var json = $.parseJSON(result);
                            $(self).remove();
                        $('#followButton').append(                                     
                     $('<a href="#" class="button unfollow" id="unfollow_'+ json +'">- unfollow</a>')
                );
                }
              });
    });
    $('.unfollow').click(function(){
        console.log('no');
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var self = this;            
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/unfollow",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result) {    
                    $(self).remove();                       
                    $('#followButton').append(                                     
                $('<a href="#" class="button follow" id="'+ result +'">+ follow</a>')
                 );
               }
          });           

    });    

});
```

**HTML:**

**Follow button:**

```
<div id="followButton">                 
  <a href="#" class="button follow" id="0-p-0">+ follow</a>
</div>
```

**Unfollow button:**

```
<div id="followButton">
        <a href="#" class="button unfollow" id="unfollow_0">- unfollow</a></div>
```

Comment: `$(self).remove();` you removed the element. Of course the event isn't getting triggered again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your buttons have been added to the DOM dynamically by an AJAX call. You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach click event on these elements:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('click','.unfollow', function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: +1, that was fast.  He should do the same with the follow as well.

Comment: And the OP should select a static parent object that is closer to the follow and unfollow buttons than the `document` object to attach the event to.